# IIS hosted WCF services and AppDomains

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have several WCF RESTful web services which are used to perform long-running tasks. They are hosted under IIS as different applications inside an IIS web site (and application pool is the same). Every service uses a singleton which resides in some Common.dll. Is there any way to guarantee that every service will have its own singleton or this is the default behavior?

Comment: @Mgetz The question is not about services lifetime but about using the same dll.

Comment: If you really meant to find out about appdomains, then I don't understand why it was marked as a duplicate...

Comment: @fejesjoco me neither, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside an application pool, different applications are hosted in different appdomains (check `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` to see it is different). So there is no way that their data can get mixed up. Even static objects will have multiple "instances" in appdomains.